# Accessing array post params in golang (gin)

Tags: go

I'm attempting to access an array of files and values posted to an API written in Gin (golang). I've got a function which takes a file, height and width. It then calls functions to resize the file, and then upload it to S3. However, I'm attempting to also upload multiple files.

```
func (rc *ResizeController) Resize(c *gin.Context) {

    file, header, err := c.Request.FormFile("file")
    filename := header.Filename

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    height := c.PostForm("height")
    width := c.PostForm("width")

    finalFile := rc.Crop(height, width, file)

    go rc.Upload(filename, finalFile, "image/jpeg", s3.BucketOwnerFull)

    c.JSON(200, gin.H{"filename": filename})
}
```

I couldn't see anywhere in the docs how to access data in the following format:

```
item[0]file
item[0]width
item[0]height
item[1]file
item[1]width
item[1]height
```

etc.

I figured something along the lines of:

```
for index, element := range c.Request.PostForm("item") {
    fmt.Println(element.Height)
}
```

But that threw "c.Request.Values undefined (type *http.Request has no field or method Values)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the `File` slice directly instead of using the `FormFile` method on `Request`. Assuming you have a form array for `width` and `height` that correspond to the order that the files were uploaded.

```
if err := ctx.Request.ParseMultipartForm(32 << 20); err != nil {
    // handle error
}

for i, fh := range ctx.Request.MultipartForm.File["item"] {
    // access file header using fh
    w := ctx.Request.MultipartForm.Value["width"][i]
    h := ctx.Request.MultipartForm.Value["height"][i]
}
```

The `FormFile` method on `Request` is just a wrapper around `MultipartForm.File` that returns the first file at that key.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Trouble is, I'm trying to get a set of data for each array item if that makes sense. So I'm not just iterating over a series of files, each iteration will contain a height and width value also.

Comment: Are you trying to derive the height and width from the uploaded file, or is it inputed when the file is uploaded?

Comment: If you are trying to derive the width and height you will have to open the file and decode the image based on mimetype to determine the width and height.

Comment: It's just a generic upload, I'm uploading several files, each given a height and width and I have a function which crops that image to the height and width etc. I'm just struggling to access the post data in rows if that makes sense?

Comment: Ok. You can just use a regular form array for width and height that correspond to the order that the files were uploaded. Then when you iterate your files you can accesses the form's Value map to get the width and height by index.

Comment: I updated my answer to illustrate how you would access width and height if they were arrays in your form post.

Comment: Thank you so much! Perfect!